# Java Serialization data mismatch

Tags: java, sockets, inheritance, serialization

I am creating a simple chat program using Java SE 7 via ServerSocket/Socket. I was wondering if it is possible to have a mismatch of data inside the sent model/entity from client to server or vise-versa? I am getting a mismatch of data from the sent model of my client to its server when I sent the same class type with different containing data consequently.

```
Example
Client: Sending...  ID: 3
Server: Received... ID: 3
Client: Sending...  ID: 4
Server: Recieved... ID: 3
```

Here my generic paradigm of my model/entity:

```
abstract class Record<T> extends Observable implements Serializable {
   // with generated "serialVersionUID" by the EclipseIDE[Juno]
   protected int id;
   // Constructor, Getters/Setters, Abstract methods
   // hashCode(): Generated by Eclipse
   // equals(): Generated by Eclipse, replacing Record with Record<T>
}
abstract class RecordVersion<T> extends Record<T> implements Serializable {
   // with generated "serialVersionUID" by the EclipseIDE[Juno]
   protected int version;
   // Constructor, Getters/Setters, Abstract methods
   // hashCode(): Generated by Eclipse
   // equals(): Generated by Eclipse, replacing RecordVersion with RecordVersion<T>
}
class SampleRecord extends RecordVersion<SampleRecord> {
   // with generated "serialVersionUID" by the EclipseIDE[Juno]
   private String data;
   // Constructor, Getters/Setters, Abstracted methods
   // hashCode(): Generated by Eclipse
   // equals(): Generated by Eclipse
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks.

UPDATE 1:

Reading the `socket.getInputStream()` via `java.io.ObjectInputStream`

```
class ReadRunnable implements Runnable {
  private Object lastObjectReceived = new Object();
  @Override
  public void run() {
    while(true) {
       try {
         // inStream: java.io.ObjectInputStream
         Object objectReceived = inStream.readObject();       
         if(objectReceived .equals(lastObjectReceived ))
           objectReceived = inStream.readObject();
         else
           lastObjectReceived = objectReceived;
       } catch(Exception e) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what debuggers are good for. You get a mismatch because you're not sending what you think you're sending, or you're not receiving what you think you're receiving.

Comment: I see... Yet I tried to dealing with the `lastObjectReceived` and comparing it to the actual `objectReceived` and comparing them if there are equal. Unfortunately, still the same problem.

Comment: Well... post some code, then.

Comment: Post the `equals()` method in each and every class that you pass over the wire (`Record`, `RecordVersion` etc).

Comment: First I didn't override `hashCode` and `equals` method of the three model/entity classes, no progress. Then I've tried to override in the `SampleRecord`, no progress. I've tried to override both methods in the abstract classes, no progress. Updated my post.

Comment: You have a bug in the `equals` method of either one (or more) of your model classes. You *must* have an `equals` method somewhere because your algorithm relies on it.

Comment: Is there another way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are attempting to send the same object instance multiple times over the same ObjectOutputStream, you are going to run into problems because Object streams preserve object identity.  in order to resend the same object instance with new data, you need to call `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` in between.

Also, in your loop you are "losing" one of the objects sent.  the first branch of your `if` block calls `.readObject()`, and then the beginning of your while loop calls `.readObject()` again, discarding the result of the previous call before comparing it.

Comment: Where would I place the `ObjectOutputStream.reset()`? Before/After the `write()` or `flush()`?

Comment: @Dr.Java - before `flush()`.  before or after `.writeObject()` doesn't really matter so long as it's called each time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I think it's best after the `.flush()`. Either way around it worked.

Comment: @Dr.Java It is best after the writeObject(), both to economise on physical writes and because it relates semantically to the writeObject(), call, not the flush() call.